# Hash stable to small changes in text

Tags: algorithm, hash

Is there a hash function that is stable to small changes in text? I'm looking for the opposite of a cryptographic hash, where small changes in the source lead to huge changes in the result.

Something like a perceptual hash for text. Is there such a thing?

Edited: by "small changes in text" I mean changes in punctuation, correction of ortographic / grammatical mistakes, etc. The text itself is an article, like a wikipedia entry (but it can be much smaller, like 2 or 3 paragraphs).

Bonus points if somebody can point to a Python implementation.

Comment: What type of text? Names? Any word? Random strings? And what sort and how big changes; for example, if names are you wanting different spellings of names; if words are you looking to see if suffixes are ignored? etc...

Comment: Like @Chris pointed out, there are many distance functions you could define. Pick one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing).